# How do I show the actual values in hex instead of the ASCII symbols

Tags: c++, hex

```
int main()
{
   char B[76]={0};

   ifstream infile;
   infile.open("tworecords.dat", ios::binary);
   infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(B), sizeof (B));

   cout << "Array B in hex" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < 76; i++)
   {
      cout << hex << B[i] << " " << endl;;
   }

   return 0;


}
```

right now it reads the data correctly, but prints out the values as ASCII symbols. I would like to output the actual hex values in the file.

example:

01
3D
76
D6
etc.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` back to something other than `char*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to integer:

```
cout << hex << static_cast<int>(B[i]) << " " << endl;
```

Or alternatively, if you don't want to cast, just add 0:

```
cout << hex << B[i]+0 << " " << endl;
```

However you probably also want to make sure that for values below 16, a leading `0` is printed (e.g. for the newline character `0A`, not just `A`):

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << B[i]+0 << " " << endl;
```

Comment: thank you! I do have another quick question though. On some of the values, there a just a bunch of f's in front before the actual value, is there anyway to get rid of them. Sorry, I'm really new at this.

Comment: @AlejandroHerrera, that is because of sign-extension. Mast the `int` using `0xFF`, e.g.: `cout << hex << (static_cast<int>(B[i]) & 0xFF) << ' ' << endl;`

Comment: The f's are there because of the sign extension that occurs in the conversion from `char` to `int`. If you can't change B to `unsigned char`, then you need to cast to `unsigned char` first, then `int`. Kind of unwieldy, but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cast the number to an integer:

```
cout << hex << (int)B[i] << " " << endl;
```

the `<iostream>` library (actually, all stream libraries) output ascii values for `char` types.

Comment: The `<iostream>` library outputs **text** for `char` types. If the system uses the ASCII encoding (as it almost certainly does), it outputs the **character** that corresponds to the ASCII value held by the `char` object.